# How can I add custom json object to Openapi spec generated by SpringBoot SpringDoc?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

My springboot project generates openapi spec using SpringDoc. I want to add a json object
to the generated spec

```
{
    "api-definition": {
      "priority": 1,
      "owner: "jack"
    }
}
```

so that the generated spec file looks like

```
{"openapi":"3.0.1",

  ................

  ................

  "api-definition": {
      "priority": 1,
      "owner: "jack"
  }
}
```

Can someone please help.

Comment: If you want to add it every time you make request to the OpenAPI endpoint, I'm not sure if that's possible. Unless you decide to rewrite the endpoint that generates the OpenAPI specification file.

Comment: Ive solved it by making use of Vendor Extensions.

Comment: Mind posting an answer on how you did it and with what extention?

Comment: @DebarghaRoy posted now. Sorry i didnt see your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this by creating an OpenApiCustomiser bean.

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

@Bean
public OpenApiCustomiser customise() {
    return openApi -> {
        try {
            openApi.setExtensions(vendorExtensions());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.error("bad json, should never happen");
        }
    };
}

private static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

private Map<String, Object> vendorExtensions() throws JsonProcessingException {
    MapType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructMapType(
            Map.class, String.class, Object.class);
    Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = new HashMap<>();

    stringObjectMap.put("api-definition",
            mapper.readValue(readFile("api-definition.json"), type));
    return stringObjectMap;
}

//To read file from resources folder
private String readFile(String fileName) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    try {
        return Files.readString(Path.of(classLoader.getResource(fileName).getFile()));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        log.error(ex.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

}
```

api-definition.json looks like below

```
{ 
  "priority": 1,
  "owner: "jack"
}
```